# Toggle Text between multiple buttons

Tags: html, wordpress, toggle

I would like to have two buttons which are basically categories. Let's name them category A and category B. The are displayed left and right. Below i would like to display some text which is dependent of the chosen category (i.e the clicked button) so that category A shows text A and category B shows text B.

This if for html. I'm working on a wordpress homepage.

I was able to install one button which toggles text (basically button 1 = Category A). But i couldn't manage to insert a second button (basically button 2 = Category B). Any ideas? Highly appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the button to swap the text of the DIV element:</p>

<p><button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button></p>

<div id="myDIV">Hello</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.innerHTML === "Hello") {
    x.innerHTML = "Swapped text!";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "Hello";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I expect to have 2 buttons which display 2 categories, the text should toggle according to which button has been clicked.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wb7efL4g/

Comment: Hi Tobias, welcome to Stackoverflow. When asking questions, please refer to the [following page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly so that we can provide a better answer to your questions. Please provide us with any code you tried and share us any problem you are having with this code (e.g. you are only using a single button in given code above).

Comment: This way seems like it would work better in the long run: https://jsfiddle.net/wb7efL4g/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could put the description in an attribute, then get the attributes value on click and change the html of the description. Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rp4umagL/)

```html
<div>
  <button class="js-button default-button" data-description="Category A's Description" onclick="myFunction(this)">
    Category A
  </button>
  <button class="js-button default-button" data-description="Category B's Description" onclick="myFunction(this)">
    Category B
  </button>
</div>

<div id="js-description" class="description">
</div>

<script>
function myFunction(elem) {
  var x = document.getElementById("js-description");
  var description = elem.getAttribute('data-description');
  x.innerHTML = description;
  
  var button = document.getElementsByClassName('js-button');
  
  for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
    button[i].classList.remove('active-button');
  }
  
  elem.classList.add('active-button');
}
</script>

<style>
  .default-button{
    font-size:16px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding:7px 12px;
  }
  .active-button{
    background:blue;
    color:#fff;
  }
  .description{
    margin-top:20px;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Smart method. I like it.

Comment: @BritishSam, how would i change the formatting of the data description? Change font size, font face and color? I'm able to format the buttons itself but i'm not able to format the description... help is highly appreciated :)

Comment: Would it be the same for each category description? If so add a class to the description div and do some css?

Comment: Yes i guess it would be the same for each category description. Let me try that, thanks !

Comment: @BritishSam Where would i need to insert my class in the category description? This is my css <style> .mystyle { color: white; font-size: 25px; } </style>

Comment: @TobiasK `<div id="js-description" class="mystyle">`

Comment: Thanks @BritishSam. I had it like this before actually but i didn't work. Found my mistake though. I had some text formatted as a header which ruined i. Thanks again for your support ;)

Comment: One last question and idea... I would love the user to be able to differentiate visually between the buttons i. e. which one is active and which is inactive. Maybe by highlighting the active button .. How could i achieve this @BritishSam?

Comment: @BritishSam wow that's awesome. This would be perfect i was using default button layout. I have formatted the buttons already and added the class to the buttons. When i use "js-button" as class it works fine but do you have an idea how i could use my own button styles and just change their color once the button is being clicked? Thanks in advance

Comment: you can add more that one class to the buttons to style them, so add like .default-button to each button then make .active-button for the active style `button class="js-button default-button"` js-button shouldn't have any style applied to it, its just for being targeted by javascript

Comment: @BritishSam how do i start with 2 unclicked buttons? right now one of them is active when the site is first visited. i would like them botch to be inactive in the beginning...

Comment: take active-button class off the first button, remove text from the js-description div

Comment: Updated answer, you could add as many button categories as you want too

Comment: amazing, thank you so much @BritishSam. This is better than every university lecture :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really like all these solutions because everything is written from JS but contents probably come from database. So here is my solution :

```js
// Native JS version
// Working Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/d34cbtw7/
var togglers = document.querySelectorAll('[data-toggle="tab"]');

for (var i = 0; i < togglers.length; i++) {
    togglers[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        var tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');
        for(var j = 0; j < tabs.length; j++) {
            tabs[j].classList.remove('active');
        }
        var $target = document.querySelector(this.getAttribute('data-target'));
        $target.classList.add('active');
    });
}

// jQuery version
$('body').on('click', '[data-toggle="tab"]', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Select our target
  var $target = $($(this).data('target'));
  // Hide all tabs
  $('.tab-contents .tab').removeClass('active');
  // Show only $target tab
  $target.addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.tab-contents .tab {
  display: none;
}
.tab-contents .tab.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-toggle="tab" data-target="#cat-A-content">
Cat A
</button>
<button data-toggle="tab" data-target="#cat-B-content">
Cat B
</button>

<div class="tab-contents">
  <div class="tab active" id="cat-A-content">
    My category A contents
  </div>
  <div class="tab" id="cat-B-content">
    My category B contents
  </div>
</div>
```

I also don't really like "onclick" attribute in HTML...

Comment: He's not using jQuery

Comment: My bad, I didn't noticed it. I've added a native JS version.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a quick codepen as example.

You can achieve this by passing a parameter to the onClick function. In this example I keep track of the last button clicked, and the text it should render. If the last button clicked was the same button, the switched back to default. I hope this helps.

https://codepen.io/maffekill/pen/rbpjzw

HTML

```
<p>Click the button to swap the text of the DIV element:</p>

<p><button onclick="myFunction(1, 'TEXT A')">TEXT A</button></p>
<p><button onclick="myFunction(2, 'TEXT B')">TEXT B</button></p>
<div id="myDIV">Default Text</div>
```

JS

```
// Keep track of the button currently clicked
var activeBtn = null; 

function myFunction(btnId, text) {

  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  // If the last button is the same as the new one, show default text
  if (activeBtn === btnId) {
    x.innerHTML = "Default Text";
    activeBtn = null
  } else {
  // Else show the text given to the text param
    x.innerHTML = text;
      activeBtn = btnId;
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this, but the easiest way I could come up with to explain this to you would be as following:

```js
function myFunction(myEle) {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  x.innerHTML = "This is category " + myEle.value;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to swap the text of the DIV element:</p>

<p>
  <button onclick="myFunction(this)" value="a">
    Category A
  </button>
  <button onclick="myFunction(this)" value="b">
    Category B
  </button>
</p>

<div id="myDIV">Hello</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s3o9hgm0/)

No need to overcomplicate things.

Firstly you would like to send the clicked element from the caller (which in this case would be the clicked element as well, the `<button>` element). You could use JavaScript's `this`for this purpose.

Within your function you can name a parameter between parenthesis, so in my example above: `function myFunction()` contains a parameter called `myEle` so it will look like: `function myFunction(myEle)`. Once the function will be triggered, the parameter called `myEle` will be set to the clicked element (or 
JavaScript's `this`). You can simply access any of its attributes like `value` by using a dot: `myEle.value`.

Knowing the above, you could apply it to whatever you require your function to do (refer to my example code above).